# Google maps API, get the users city/ nearest city/ general area

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been trying to code a function that returns the most reasonable, moderately sized city/ town/ region a person is in or near.

Apps such as yik yak used an algorithim like this to group people together. Is there any existing alogorithims to do this? At the moment I'm using this:

```
 geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function (results, status) {

        var city = 'Unknown';
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

            var details = results[0].address_components;

            for (var i = details.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
                for (var j=0; j<details[i].types.length;j++) {

                    if (details[i].types[j] == 'locality') {
                        city = details[i].long_name;
                    } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'sublocality') {
                        city = details[i].long_name;
                    } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'neighborhood') {
                        city = details[i].long_name;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Which isn't the best. I've just tried to enter these coords: {latitude: 53.4808, longitude: -2.7426}

And got unknown. When looking as the results the geocoder returned, I see Saint Helens would be the most reasonably sized group to put this user in. If that didn't exist, I see Merseysid is also returned which would be the next best thing.

Comment: I see a starting comment with `/*`. Is it a bug or a feature? Please, post json result here.

Comment: oh i was experiemented and forgot to take that away when making the question

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like both Saint Helens and Mersyside are in the result from the Reverse Geocoder.

**reverse geocoder result:**

```
[
  {"long_name":"Unnamed Road","short_name":"Unnamed Road","types":["route"]},
  {"long_name":"Saint Helens","short_name":"Saint Helens","types":["postal_town"]},
  {"long_name":"Merseyside","short_name":"Merseyside","types":["administrative_area_level_2","political"]},
  {"long_name":"England","short_name":"England","types":["administrative_area_level_1","political"]},
  {"long_name":"United Kingdom","short_name":"GB","types":["country","political"]},
  {"long_name":"WA11","short_name":"WA11","types":["postal_code","postal_code_prefix"]}
]
```

If you add those types to your `if` statement, the it will appear in the result:

```
  for (var i = details.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
    for (var j=0; j<details[i].types.length;j++) {
      if (details[i].types[j] == 'locality') {
        city = details[i].long_name;
      } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'sublocality') {
        city = details[i].long_name;
      } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'neighborhood') {
        city = details[i].long_name;
      } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'postal_town') {
        city = details[i].long_name;
      } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'administrative_area_level_2') {
        city = details[i].long_name;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log("city="+city);
}
```

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/of6Lvdf7/2/)

**code snippet:**

```js
var geocoder;
var map;

function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.4808, -2.7426),
      zoom: 12,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: map.getCenter(),
  });
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'latLng': new google.maps.LatLng(53.4808, -2.7426)
  }, function(results, status) {

    var city = 'Unknown';
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

      var details = results[0].address_components;
      console.log(JSON.stringify(details));
      for (var i = details.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        for (var j = 0; j < details[i].types.length; j++) {
          if (details[i].types[j] == 'locality') {
            city = details[i].long_name;
          } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'sublocality') {
            city = details[i].long_name;
          } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'neighborhood') {
            city = details[i].long_name;
          } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'postal_town') {
            city = details[i].long_name;
            console.log("postal_town=" + city);
          } else if (details[i].types[j] == 'administrative_area_level_2') {
            city = details[i].long_name;
            console.log("admin_area_2=" + city);
          }
        }
      }
      console.log("city=" + city);
      document.getElementById('city').innerHTML = "city=" + city;
    }
  })
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map_canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="city"></div>
<div id="map_canvas"></div>
```

Comment: thanks, i was mainly wondering if there was a better way to do this, a more sophisticated algorithim out there? ill test this one of a few places and see how it performs

Comment: im sure algorithims used for apps like yik yak and private but alot of apps like this are coming to surface, maybe they just did a long if else statment like mine?